# Comparar campos de 2 tablas y modificar 1 de ellas y una 3er tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo 2 tablas.

Necesito llenar la table 3 con los id, de los registros de las tablas(1 y 2) cuando estos coinciden.

Tener en cuenta que en la tabla 1, hay 1,5 millón de registros y en la tabla 2 100mil.

[image: Tabla 1]

[image: Tabla 2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]